# Cannot read property 'getRange' of null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the below filter function to copy data from one sheet to another,
filtering out so that it only saved data in the 'Data Entry' if column Q23 = FALSE.
I already treat Q23 as a text (=TO_TEXT(R29))

```
function SubmitData01() {
  
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var where     = ss.getSheetByName('Data Entry');
  var triggerCell = where.getRange('Q29').getValue();
      
  if (triggerCell == 'TRUE'){} else  // If the cell is true do nothing
  if (triggerCell == 'FALSE'){   // If the cell is false run the script
  
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName('Data Entry');
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName('Address'); 
  var values = [[formSS.getRange("A29").getValue(), 
                 formSS.getRange("I9").getValue(),formSS.getRange("E9").getValue(), 
                 formSS.getRange("E10").getValue(),]];
  
                datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 4).setValues(values);
       }
```

When I use the above script, I get the error message:

> "Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (line 5, file "saved")".

Comment: Tale as old as time: `var where     = ss.getSheetByName('Data Entry');`. You probably typoed in the sheet name (or there is no such sheet), hence `null` ( `getSheetByName` returns it on failure to find )

Comment: Thanks, @OlegValter, I revise it already.

Comment: Kat, thank you for confirming, glad you resolved the issue - I am voting to close the question since it is just typo (although ziganotschka's answer provides value, so the Q&A is worth keeping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The error `Cannot read property 'getRange' of null` means that the script cannot find the specified range
- The most common reason of this error is that the sheet with specified name does not exist
- Mind that Apps Script is case sensitive and also spaces count as characters
- So

`Data Entry`

is not the same like

`DataEntry`

or

`Data entry`

Comment: I did typo on the sheetname, thank youuu, I already fixed it @ziganotschka